# Javascript pass array to function in class

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Please let me know, why my function is not working,

```
class sort{

constructor(array){

  this.array=array;
}

/* Buble soring */
  bubble_sort(){

      let swapped = false;


      for(let i=0; i<this.array.length; i++){
            if(this.array[i]>this.array[i+1]){
              /* Swapping method */
              let temp = this.array[i+1];
              this.array[i] = this.array[i];
              this.array[i] = this.array[i+1];
              this.array[i+1] =temp;
              return this.array;
            };
      };

  };
};


let d = new sort([5,4,3,2,1]);

console.log(d.bubble_sort())
```

Comment: Use a debugger to figure out what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works yet in order to make it a bubble sort you need 2 loops. With one loop you'll basically just sort the first number.

```
class sort {
  constructor(array) {
    this.array = array;
  }

  /* Buble soring */

  bubble_sort() {
    let swapped = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
      if (this.array[i] > this.array[i + 1]) {
        /* Swapping method */
        let temp = this.array[i + 1];
        this.array[i + 1] = this.array[i];
        this.array[i] = temp;
      }
    }
    return this.array;
  }
}

let d = new sort([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]);

console.log(d.bubble_sort());
```